# Как загрузить файл в synaptic?

Tags: linux, altlinux

После отмечания файла нажимаю выполнить (altlinux5.0), но программа выдает такое

> `w: Не удалось получить file:///media/linux/p5/i586/RPMS.classic/gibc-preinstall-2.11.2-alt.M51.1.i586.rpmFile not Found`

Подскажите, что нужно сделать? И желательно подробнее.

Comment: На случай, если вы доступаетесь через прокси: [Настройка Synaptic для работы с MS Proxy Server].

Comment: Там file стоит в начале, proxy не причем

Comment: Да, правильно, прокси не причем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В репозиторий нельзя добавлять файлы, туда надо добавлять ссылки на репозитории с пакетами, а если надо просто поставить уже скачанный пакет, то можно использовать

```
apt-get install /media/linux/p5/i586/RPMS.classic/gibc-preinstall-2.11.2-alt.M51.1.i586.rpm
```

А если нужно добавить например скачанный и смотированный в папку диск то нужно писать

```
rpm file:///путь_к_смонтированному_диску/ i586 classic
```

Comment: В репозиторий нельзя добавлять файлы, -- обратного не кто не утверждал

Answer (score 1):

Похоже не может в репозиторий найти файлпопробуйте др. репозиторий

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: только перед этим нужно выключить локальный репозиторий в /etc/apt/sources.list.d/http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_ALT_Linux

Answer (score 1):

Уберите сразу из репозитория инсталляционный CD! Его он и просит, а тот ни вставлен ни смонтирован. Настройки - Репозитории. И получайте пакеты только новые из сетевых репозиториев!